# Inputting into another application with C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys, spy++

I want fill IP , User and Pass for kerio vpn client from my C# application but i can't find name of user/ip/pass textbox ! i use from spy++ but it's not enough !

also i can do that with sendkeys like this :

```
 SendKeys.Send("1.2.3.4{TAB}User{TAB}Pass{ENTER}");
```

but this is not really good idea bxs if for somethings focus is not on the server ip we get failed ! also i want to fix this issue with exit app and open again but i got failed with this method , when i exit and open again focused is not always on server ip one time on user on other time on pass and maybe on server ip so that is not work  !

finally i want to fill textbox i want to use some methods like kaspesky antivirus for fill user and pass so check this app with spy++ and get this : (please see this pic :)

[image]

Now anyone can help me and have any solution for me ?

Comment: VPN is pretty simple to implement.  Put yourself into the shoes of a VPN utility vendor.  What feature would you use to distinguish yourself from everybody else that can implement it?  If you guessed "security" then you are half-way to figuring out why this will not ever work.

Comment: @HansPassant I Want to create an free app which help and comfortable for user for connect to almost all of vpn client like OVPN - Kerio - PPTP etc so i need a way for connect .... ! now do you know any way or solution for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the client application was made by using [qt widget toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29).
As far as I know, the library doesn't support such things.

Take a look at this:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/39541

Comment: So you think this is not possible ! well have any solution for first focuse ? why when we open client app focused is not always on special section (Only on Windows 8 and 7)....have any solution ?